# How to find the Chrome extension that opened a spam website?

Tags: google-chrome, spam-prevention

Currently I have a weird problem: I do a Google search and probably once a day, one of my clicks onto a search result does not lead to the target site but instead opens a spam site.

Today's example:

1. I have searched for "Materialnetzwerk genossenschaft" on google.lt
2. Then clicked the first link `https://www.materialnetzwerk.org/` (do not visit!)
3. Chrome opens suddenly: `http://play1948.check-vestamoney52.loan/4691354950/?t=main7_5&u=gmqk605&o=55hppzy&f=1`

which redirects to `https://best.prizedeal16.info/?utm_term=6587232470498805734&clickverify=1&utm_content=fdc2c69a9cafac9c9b9190a197979095ba88b8ccbecabcbd838a8281b68e83818aa6b9b1be8fbd8d82b280818687b585ddf4f7fef2fabcd4fcf0be91a4a394a7deebe8e9888e809e87e3e0d0e6d6ddd7cafbc9c9c6cffccdc2c6c8c1c1c6c5f5fefbfcf9fefdfffff2f3a2f8f6fff4f559`

In worst case, but I doubt, my Windows 10 installation is compromised. – My bet is that it is one of the Chrome extension.

That's why I would like to find out which extension is responsible for the redirect or manipulating the URLs.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the same approach that you used and by searching for "Materialnetzwerk genossenschaft" on Google and found the same link in position 1. (If nothing else, this will confirm that your OS is not compromised.)

The link you mentioned is attached to a redirect. The link is a 'scam' in that it redirects to the URL that you mentioned which is not the link advertised. This is not your chrome installation. It is the site itself.

It is curious that this redirect happens only the first time you run this search. Thereafter it reports that the site can't be reached.

This site should be reported to Google on [Google Safe Browsing](https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_phish/?hl=en).

Visitors to the post above should not emulate your search and click the link because this is exactly what the 'scammers' want.

I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much for the enlightenment. It happened to me a couple of times over the last weeks, with different URLs. As it seems, there are more and more scam sites popping up in the top results of Google. (PS: First I wanted to ask you if you are using the same extension as I do )

Comment: I use Adobe Acrobat, Google Docs, Logitech Smooth Scrolling Restlet Client, XDebug Helper, Chrome Apps Developer Tool and Postman extensions. I tried disabling all of these but as the link only worked the first time, I could not repeat the outcome. I tried on other browsers and always got the broken site message.

Comment: Maybe they track the IP. Maybe somebody else can confirm the first time redirect and second visit blank page?